# Test for concavity.

Tags: calculus

Prove that $r \cos n\theta = a$ is concave towards the pole .
 I tried $u= \frac{1}{r}$, and calculate $ u+ \frac{d^2 u}{d\theta^2}$, we get

$\frac{1-n^2}{a}\cos n\theta$, then how to conclude about concavity

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76708/how-to-determine-a-shape-is-convex-by-giving-polar-form-polynomial-equation/76745#76745), Robert Israel explained that the curve would be convex if

$$C=r^2 + 2 (r')^2 - r r'' \ge 0$$ Using 
$$r=a \sec (n t)\qquad r'=a n \tan (n t) \sec (n t)\qquad r''=a n^2 \sec (n t) \left(2 \sec ^2(n t)-1\right)$$ you should arrive to 
$$C=-a^2 \left(n^2-1\right) \sec ^2(n t)$$ Now, you can use series expansion around $t=\frac{\pi }{2 n}$ and get
$$\sec (n t)=-\frac{1}{n \left(t-\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)}-\frac{1}{6} n \left(t-\frac{\pi }{2
   n}\right)+O\left(\left(t-\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)^3\right)$$
$$\sec^2(n t)=\frac{1}{n^2 \left(t-\frac{\pi }{2
   n}\right)^2}+\frac{1}{3}+O\left(\left(t-\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)^2\right)$$

Just continue.