# How to check the convexity of this function?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix, convex-hulls

I have a function $g(x,y,\alpha)$ that for $g(x,y,\alpha)=0$ defines a closed surface of $x$ and $y$. Depending on the varable $\alpha$ the shape of the surface changes, see the figure below[[image: The dependence of the function <span class=]$g$ on the parameter $\alpha$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg5QN.jpg).

As you can see in the figure, upon increasing the parameter $\alpha$, the shape of the closed surface changes and corners are created. 
I would like to find the critical value of $\alpha$ for which the closed surface $g(x,y,\alpha)=0$ is not convex anymore.

The function $g$ is a bit complex but I provide its expression just in case it is needed

$g=-0.049(\frac{1}{1+\alpha^3})^\frac{1}{3}+((x^2 +x y + y^2)^\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3\sqrt{3} x y (x+y)(-1+\alpha^3)}{2(1+\alpha^3)})^\frac{1}{3}$.

$\textbf{What I did so far:}$

I know that for the function $g(x,y,\alpha)$ to be convex its Hessian matrix should be positive semi-definite. So I calculated the Hessian as follows

$\mathbf{H}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\displaystyle \partial^2 g}{\displaystyle \partial x^2} & \frac{\displaystyle\partial^2 g}{\displaystyle \partial x \partial y} \\
\frac{\displaystyle \partial^2 g}{\displaystyle \partial y \partial x} & \frac{\displaystyle \partial^2 g}{\displaystyle \partial y^2}
\end{pmatrix}$.

In order to ensure the positive semi-definiteness of the Hessian $\mathbf{H}$, its eigenvalues must be positive. Thus, it should satisfy the following conditions:

1. $\det(\mathbf{H})>0$.
2. $\frac{\displaystyle \partial^2 g}{\displaystyle \partial x^2}>0$.

However, after calculating I understood that $\det(\mathbf{H})$ is zero for every $\alpha$ and also $\frac{\displaystyle \partial^2 g}{\displaystyle \partial x^2}$ is too complex. Therefore I couldn't determine the positive semi-definiteness of $\mathbf{H}$ with this procedure.

I would like to know if I am on the right path for the determination of the critical value of $\alpha$ for which the surface $g$ is not convex. If yes, then how can I continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to polar coordinates $x = r \cos(\theta)$, $y=r \sin(\theta)$, and you can explicitly parametrize your curve as $r = R(\theta)$.  The [criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76708/how-to-determine-a-shape-is-convex-by-giving-polar-form-polynomial-equation/76745#76745) for a smooth polar curve
to be convex is  $r^2 + 2 (r')^2 - r r'' \ge 0$ for all $\theta$, which is rather a mess here.  Numerically minimizing $\alpha$ subject to the constraint $R^2 + 2 (R')^2 - R R'' = 0$, I find that the critical $\alpha$ is approximately $1.44224957028754$.

Comment: That's the cube root of 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the last equation, there should be $R^2+2(R')^2-R R''=0$, right? And also the second question. How did you parametrize the curve as $r=T(\theta)$? Isn't is too complex?

Comment: But I didn't understand exactly what you did that you got $\alpha=1.4422495...$. What did you minimize exactly? Could you explain more please?

Comment: @Empy2 Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce $z=-x-y$ so it is a shape on the plane $x+y+z=0$.  Then there are $(r,\theta)$ with
$$x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\cos(\theta+2\pi/3)\\
z=r\cos(\theta-2\pi/3)$$
Then the equation is 
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}-cxyz=d\\
r^3(1-p\cos3\theta)=q$$
You can work out $p$ and $q$ in terms of $\alpha$.
Then $x=r\cos\theta$ so 
$$x^3=\frac{q\cos^3\theta}{1-p\cos3\theta}$$
The shape is convex if $x$ has a local maximum at $\theta=0$ Find the value of $p$ for which the second derivative $d^2(1/x^3)/d\theta^2=0$.