# "Flower" petal set in convex analysis: when it is non empty and show that is convex

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

I am trying to solve an exercise of convex analysis. I think it's easy but I am already stuck.

Let $a,b \in R^n$ with $a \neq b$.
For any $\delta \in (0, +\infty)$ we define the flower petal associated
to $\delta, a, b$ as follows

$P_\delta(a, b) $=$ \{x ∈ R^n: \delta||x-a||+||x-b||<||b-a||\}.$

i. For which values of $\delta$ is $P_\delta(a, b) $ nonempty?

ii. Show that $P_\delta(a, b) $ is convex.

iii. (Draw $P_\delta(a, b)$ if $\delta$ = 1/3 and $\delta$ = 1/2).

I am pretty sure it's probably pretty obvious.

I thought about using the triangle inequality or one of its variations combined the fact that if $x \in [a,b]$ then x can be written as $x=\lambda b + (1 - \lambda)a$ with $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Due to the last request and the triangle inequality, I suppose that $\lambda<1$ but i wouldn't know how to prove it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(See also Edit 1 below).

We will fix $a,b$ and denote $P_{\delta}=P_{\delta}(a,b)$.

A first remark is that

$$\delta_1 < \delta_2 \ \implies \ P_{\delta_1} \supset P_{\delta_2}\tag{1}$$

Indeed, this is an immediate consequence of the fact that, for a given point $X$, if  $\delta_1 < \delta_2 $,

$$\delta_1 \|x-a\|+\|x-b\|<\|a-b\|  \ \implies \ \delta_2 \|x-a\|+\|x-b\|<\|a-b\| $$

Let us work on frontier curves $\partial P_{\delta}$ defined by :

$$\delta \|x-a\|+\|x-b\|=\|a-b\|$$

Here is an answer to part iii) in the planar case for different values of $\delta$ displayed with a stepsize equal to $0.1$.

As established in (1), these sets constitute a descending chain like russian dolls (see figure) with

$$-1 < \delta < 1$$

1. For the range of values
   $$0 \le \delta 
    < 1,$$

one gets **convex sets**:

For $\delta=0$ : it is the interior of the circle centered in $b$ with radius $b-a$ (displayed in red);  all the other domains,  for $\delta = 0.1, 0.2,$ etc. are interior to this circle, till $\delta=0.9$, the interior of the smallest petal. The case $\lambda=1$ corresponds to the interior of line segment $BA$ (case of equality $BM+MA=BA$ in the triangular inequality), this interior being void...

2. Whereas for the complementary range of values :

$$ -1 < \delta <0,$$

sets $P_{\delta}$ are still non void but **none of them convex**
completing the previous ones to make ["limaçon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on) frontier curves (proof below in the "Edit" part) ; all of them are exterior to the red circle.

Please note the way the frontier is gradually pinched in point $a$.

[image]

---

**Edit 1** : We can also answer to question ii). The definition of $P_{\delta}$ involving only mutual distances, one can use a translation and a rotation such that point $a$ is placed at the origin and $b$ is placed at abscissa $b>0$ on the $x$ axis, without loss of generality.

This will allow to use polar coordinates for the current point

$$x=(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) \in P_{\delta}.\tag{2}$$

As $a=0$, the constraint becomes:

$$\delta \|x\|+\|x-b\| < \|b\| \tag{3}$$

(3) can be written, taking (2) into account :

$$\delta r + \sqrt{b^2+r^2-2br \cos(\theta)}<1$$

which is equivalent (under the condition $1-\delta r > 0$) to:

$$b^2+r^2-2br \cos(\theta)<(1-\delta r)^2$$

itself equivalent to:

$$r < \underbrace{\frac{2b}{\delta^2-1}(\delta-\cos(\theta))}_{\rho(\theta)}\tag{4}$$

which can be described as the interior of the internal loop (in blue) of a ["limaçon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on), as said earlier, and it is convex (see explanation at the bottom of this answer).

[image]

Please note that, in order to keep $r \ge 0$, the range of polar angle $\theta$ has to be :

$$\cos(\theta)\ge\delta \ \ \iff \ \ -\operatorname{acos}(\delta) \le \theta \le \operatorname{acos}(\delta)\tag{5}$$

**Remark:** extension to 3D is straightforward because it is the drop-like volume of revolution obtained by rotating the convex blue curve around $x$ axis, therefore itself convex.

**Explanation about convexity:** A classical convexity criteria for polar equations $\rho=\rho(\theta)$ is

$$\rho^2+2\rho'^2-\rho \rho'' \ge 0$$

(with $\rho$ given by (4)) because it amounts to condition

$$\delta(\delta-\cos \theta) \ge 0$$

which is verified indeed (see condition (5)) for the small loops.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76708/305862)

---

Edit 2: The limaçon curve is found in different cases. Here is an unexpected one connected to the "moiré" phenomenon, so striking that it is on the front cover of a book by a colleague that I give here:

[image]

It is obtained by the superposition of two identitical circular gratings, one slightly shifted with respect to the other.

Comment: Convexity condition is connected to curvature formula for polar curves that can be found [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-curvature-of-plane-polar-curves)