# Maximum Volume of a Solid of Revolution

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

> The region $D$ is formed by the area under a curve of length $\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$ that connected points $(\ln(1+\sqrt{2}), \sqrt{2})$ and $(\sqrt{2}, 2)$. What is the maximum volume of the solid of revolution obtained by rotating the region $D$ around the $x$-axis?

$$
\begin{align*}
& I(f)=\int\limits_{\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}^{\sqrt{2}}\pi f^2\ dx+\lambda\left(\ \int\limits_{\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}^{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{1+f'^2}\ dx-\ln(1+\sqrt{2})\right)\\\\
& (1+f'^2)(f^2-c^2)=\lambda^2\\\\
& ds=\frac{c_2}{c_1-f^2}\ dx\\
\end{align*}
$$
I'm stuck on solving this differential equation. I'm not sure if it can be solved with parametric equations or some "trick".

Comment: Here is a [related question and answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346030/calculus-of-variations-find-ya-2-if-yx-maximizes-the-volume-of-rotation). The solution involves elliptic curves, and might not have a closed form. I attempted using the Euler-Lagrange equation on functional $$F(x,f,f')=\pi f^2 +\lambda\sqrt{1+f'^2}\,,$$ which yields $$2\pi f-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\lambda f'}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}}\right)=0$$ but did not go further.