# Among all shapes with the same area, a circle has the shortest perimeter

Tags: geometry

Is it true that "Among all shapes with the same area, a circle has the shortest perimeter"  ? and how to prove it ?

Comment: Yes actually. You can also say that a sphere will have the greatest volume for a fixed surface area compared to any other shape.

Comment: See [Isoperimetric Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality)

Comment: [Strongly related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/why-does-a-circle-enclose-the-largest-area).

Answer (score 12):

The question can be asked such as "Find the plane curve which encloses given area with shortest perimeter". Then by parametric formulation of coordinates $x(t),y(t)$ and assuming non-selfintersecting curve the area can be written as
$$A=\frac 12 \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\big(xy'-x'y\big)dt$$
and the perimeter
$$I=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}dt$$
Then the Euler-Lagrange becomes
$$-\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{x'}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}\bigg)-\frac{\lambda}2\bigg(y'+\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(y\bigg)\bigg)=0$$
$$-\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{y'}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}\bigg)-\frac{\lambda}2\bigg(-x'-\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(x\bigg)\bigg)=0$$
If $ds$ is the element of arc the equations can be reduced to
$$\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}+\lambda \frac{dy}{ds}=0$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{ds^2}-\lambda \frac{dx}{ds}=0$$
which has the solution
$$x(t)=K_1+C_1\cos(\lambda s)+C_2\sin(\lambda s)$$
$$y(t)=K_2-C_2\cos(\lambda s)+C_2\sin(\lambda s)$$
It can be further simplified by "Angle sum and difference identities"
$$x(t)=K_1+D\sin(\lambda s+\alpha)$$
$$y(t)=K_2-D\cos(\lambda s+\alpha)$$
where $D\sin(\alpha)=C_1$ and $D\cos(\alpha)=C_2$; and this solution represents a circle of radius $D$ and centre $(K_1,K_2)$

Answer (score 9):

This is true and classical, and not quite as trivial as one might think. This also works in higher dimensions.

For a real-life argument - look at the shape water drops take! Or even more convincingly: look at soap bubbles (thanks to [fgp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42986/fgp) for this example).

For an intuition why this should be true mathematically, try the following reasoning:

Let $F$ be the figure with the shortest perimeter from among figures with a given area. Try cutting the figure $F$ by a line $l$ in such a way that both parts have the same area. Call these parts $F_1 $ and $F_2$.

The illuminating observation is that you could now construct another figure $F'$ with same area as $F$. This is achieved by replacing $F_2$ by the reflection of $F_1$ with respect to $l$; i.e. take $F' := F_1 \cup R_l(F_1)$, where $R_l$ is the reflection with respect to $l$. Of course, we can also take $F'' := F_2 \cup R_l(F_2)$. Because the areas $\operatorname{Area}(F_1)$ and $\operatorname{Area}(F_2)$ are equal (and have the value $\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Area}(F)$), the new figures have areas $\operatorname{Area}(F') = \operatorname{Area}(F'') = \operatorname{Area}(F) $. Likewise, we have $\operatorname{Perimeter}(F') = 2 \operatorname{Perimeter}(F_1)$ (here, we are not counting the part of the perimeter that lies on $l$), $\operatorname{Perimeter}(F'') = 2 \operatorname{Perimeter}(F_2)$ and of course: 
$$\operatorname{Perimeter}(F) = \operatorname{Perimeter}(F_1) + \operatorname{Perimeter}(F_2) = \frac{\operatorname{Perimeter}(F') + \operatorname{Perimeter}(F'')}{2} $$
If $F_1$ and $F_2$ had different perimeters, then one of $F'$, $F''$ would have a smaller perimeter than $F$, and the same area. But we assumed that $F$ was optimal, so $\operatorname{Perimeter}(F_1) = 2 \operatorname{Perimeter}(F_2)$.

Let us push this idea a little further. Note that $F'$ and $F''$ are now again optimal, in the sense that they have the same area as $F$. This means, they have to be convex (if a figure is not convex, you can make a "shortcut" at its concavity, making the perimeter shorter and area larger; but it is easy to get rid of the extra area without increasing the perimeter, for instance by scaling). This means, among other things, that the lines perpendicular to $l$ through the intersection points with $F$ are tangent to $F$ (so if $F$ has a well defined tangent at this points, the tangent is perpendicular to $l$). This doesn't yet show that $F$ has to be a circle, but we see that $F$ has a lot of symmetry that only the circle seems to have.

With a little more work, we can almost get from here to the solution. Note that instead of working with $F$, can work with $F'$, i.e. we can assume that the figure is symmetric with respect to $l$. But this is equivalent to just considering $F_1$. Let us denote the two points where $l$ meets $F$ by $A,B$, and let $C$ be a point at the boundary of $F_1$. The lines $AB,BC,CA$ cut $F_1$ into three regions: triangle $ABC$ and two irregular shapes touching lines $AC$ and $BC$. We can do two things now. The idea from *Cut the knot* is to transform $ABC$ by changing the length of $AB$ Because $\operatorname{Area}(ABC) = \frac{1}{2} |AC| \cdot |CB| \cdot \sin \angle C$, we can assume that $\angle C = \pi/2$. Another possibility is to reflect the area adjacent to $AC$ an conclude that the tangent to $F$ at $C$ meets $AC$ at the same angle as the tangent at $A$ meets $AC$. Doing the same for $BC$ an counting angles, we again conclude that $\angle C = \pi/2$. But $\angle C = \pi/2$ means that $C$ lies on the half-circle based on $F_1$. So $F_1$ is a half-circle, an we are done!

Of course, there is some cheating involve in assuming the best figure exists. Also, at a few steps I assumed existence of tangents. This can be explained away, but Im not sure if it's of interest here.

For a detailed discussion, this seems relevant: [Cut the knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/isoperimetric.shtml) (which I used it here strongly, but most of the ideas are mathematical folklore).

Comment: thank you all for the reflexion tracks you gave me :)

Answer (score 2):

I will try to add "Easier" solution yet it requires 2 assumptions:

1. The shape is formed of edges.
2. Given a shape formed of $ n $ edges and perimeter $ P $ the largest area will be if all edges are equal in their length.

Namely, if the question is limited to [Polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) with equal edges the following will hold.

If we take those 2 assumptions something nice happens.
Since the shape is symmetric it has a center and the distance from its center to any vertex is equal.
Let's define the distance to each vertex as $ r $.
What is formed is [Isosceles Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle) composed from two edges of the length $ r $ and a base of the length $ \frac{P}{n} $.
The area of this triangle is given by $ {A}_{n} = \frac{r}{2} \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \frac{P}{n} $.

Since there are $ n $ triangles just like this the area is given by $ A = \frac{r}{2} \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right) P $.

Now, to maximize the area one needs to maximize the term $ \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right) $ which is maximized for $ n \to \infty $ which suggests a shape of a circle.

Dedicated with love to Renana!