# Do balls optimize the boundary area for a fixed volume?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, optimization

I recently saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389339/among-all-shapes-with-the-same-area-a-circle-has-the-shortest-perimeter/389362#389362), asking if the circle is the planar figure which has the least perimeter given the area. As far as I know, this is a classical problem, and the answer is affirmative. I am also fairly certain that the same is true for the ball in three dimensions: given a fixed volume, the solid with that volume and minimal area is the ball.

However, I realised with some surprise that I do not know if this generalises to higher dimensions. Hence the **question**:

> Consider all $n$-dimensional manifolds with doundary $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$
>    with $\operatorname{vol}(M) = 1$. Is it true that
>   $\operatorname{vol}(\partial M)$ is minimised by the ball (with the
>   appriate radius)?

I think this should be true, but I am also aware that high-dimensional geometry can produce very unexpected results, so I am far from being certain.

*(Because everything happens in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I believe there is a natural notion of volume on submanifolds; I denote this volume by $\operatorname{vol}$)*

Comment: Do you really mean to say "volume to area"? In the body of the post the question is clearer: the volume of the manifold and the volume of its perimeter.

Comment: See wikiepedia: [Isoperimetric inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality)

Comment: @rschwieb: Apologies for the vague wording of the topic, I hope it is better now. It would be more precise to say "$(n-1)$-dimensional volume of the boundary", I suppose, but hopefully it is understandable enough.

Comment: For 3 dimension, it's indeed true, and it's the reason why soap bubbles and water drops are spherical! (In their steady state, at least).  They minimize their surface area, since a larger area translates to a higher energy state in a way, and they do tend to be in the state with the lowest energy.

Comment: This is the classical [isoperimetric inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality).  To get started, see the section on [higher dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#Isoperimetric_inequality_in_higher_dimensions) in the Wikipedia article, which has references to some textbooks where the proof can be found.

Comment: Many thanks for the reference to isoperimetric inequality, that is apparently what I was looking for.