# Why is this method of proving that circle encloses the maximum area for a given perimeter turning out to be wrong?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, optimization, proof-writing, calculus-of-variations

I tried to do this in polar coordinates setting the perimeter to $L_0$ and using 'by parts' to break this integral down.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}rd{\theta} = L_0$$ and $$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}r^2d{\theta}$$.

Integration by parts leads to

$$\frac{1}{2}(L_0r(0) - \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int rd\theta\frac{dr}{d\theta}d{\theta})=\frac{1}{2}L_0r(0)-\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}r^2d{\theta}$$

So $A = \frac{1}{2}L_0r(0) - \frac{1}{2}A$ and $A = \frac{1}{3}L_0r(0)$. where $r(0)$ is the radius at an arbitrary point.

I was hoping to find an equation for the area that I could use $r(\theta)$ to maximise (by intuition), instead I got quite possibly the most ridiculous answer. Namely, that the area of all 2d shapes is $\frac{1}{3}L_0r(0)$. Why is this?

Comment: One way to prove it, is to maximize the ratio $A/L_0^2$ using Euler–Lagrange equation. I did it once, and after some algebra found that the ratio is extremal when the curvature is constant.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/why-does-a-circle-enclose-the-largest-area)?

Comment: @PaulAljabar It's not exactly because i'm asking specifically about problems with this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=f(\theta) $ and $g(\theta) =\int_{0}^{\theta}f(t)\,dt$ then $L=g(2\pi)$ and we have $$2A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta) f(\theta) \, d\theta=f(2\pi)L-\int_{0}^{2\pi}f'(\theta)g(\theta)\,d\theta$$ Now you have tried to express the second integral as $(1/2)\int_{0}^{2\pi}f^{2}(\theta)\,d\theta$ which is clearly wrong. The problem is that the equation $$r\, d\theta\frac{dr} {d\theta} =r\, dr$$ is valid but the equation in question $$\left(\int r\, d\theta\right) \frac{dr} {d\theta} $$ and the first factor in parentheses is no longer a differential, but it has already been integrated to yield a function $g(\theta) $. The confusion arises only due to the fact that you have not used parentheses. Be careful while using integration by parts. You can also see that the problem is avoided if we use a different function symbol $g$ for anti-derivarive of $f$.

Comment: is it feasible to continue this method to at least gain a rough intuition as to how it's a circle?

Comment: @gebra: the right tool here is calculus of variations rather than usual calculus. Unfortunately I am not even a novice in calculus of variations. Please ask this as a question and I am sure there are experts here on this topic to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not "integration" directly but this is a standard problem in "Calculus of Variations": http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CalculusofVariations.html.

https://www.uu.edu/dept/math/SeniorPapers/03-04/Goshi.pdf

Comment: why specifically is this method flawed?