# Maximun area cover by a rope.

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Consider a rope of fixed length $ k $. If we link the extremes of the rope in order to form a closed curve, what is the maximun area that we can cover?

More formally:

Let $ k \in \mathbb{R}^+ $. We consider all piecewise $ C^1 $ closed curves $ \delta : [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that $ L_a^b ( \delta ) = k $ (length of $ \delta $). For each $ \delta $, let be $ D_{ \delta } \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that $ \partial D_{ \delta } = \delta([a,b]) $ (the surface cover by $ \delta $). What is the maximun value of 
$$
\int_{ D_{ \delta } } 1
$$
over all the possible curves $ \delta $?

I tried to use Green's Theorem because it gives a relation between the curve $ \partial D_{ \delta }  $ and the area of $ D_{ \delta }  $. If $ \delta(t) = ( \delta_1 (t), \delta_2 (t) ) $ and $ F(x,y) = (0,x) $, then Green's Theorem allow us to write 
$$
\int_{ D_{ \delta } } 1 = 
\int_{ \partial  D_{ \delta } } F = 
\int_a^b F( \delta_1 (t), \delta_2 (t) ) \cdot (\delta_1' (t), \delta_2' (t) ) \ dt = 
\int_a^b \delta_1 (t) \cdot \delta_2' (t) \ dt
$$
while $ L_a^b( \delta ) = \int_a^b \sqrt{ \delta_1' (t)^2 + \delta_2' (t)^2} \ dt $.

It gives an expresion of that we want to maximize and the restriction, and both expresion are similar in a certain way, but this does not seem useful (at least for me). Intuitively, I think that the solution is to consider a circle of lenght $ k $, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: You're right in that the solution is a circle of circumference $k$! I'm not familiar with a solution but https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/why-does-a-circle-enclose-the-largest-area one of the solutions given here uses Green's theorem to prove the isoperimetric inequality from which it follows

Comment: Thanks! I have been searching for question similar here, but I haven't found anyting. @OsamaGhani

Comment: Consider k=2(a+b), the product a x b is maximum when a=b. That is maximum area for a no circle shape is when the shape is square, its area is k^2/16. Now compare with when it is a circle with area k^2/ (4.x 3.14).clearly area of circle is greater.