# What shape maximises area for a given perimeter?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I know that the answer is a circle, and that the branch of mathematics from which it can be proved is the calculus of variations, but I would like to know if a proof exists which I can understand at my level. I am a high school student, and I have completed the school curriculum on calculus.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/why-does-a-circle-enclose-the-largest-area

Comment: See if you could prove that the area of a regular polygon is maximized if **1.** the apothem and radius have the same length, or **2.** the angle between the apothem and radius (or even two adjacent radii) is $0$.